# Linking to a Bootstrap Tab from outside

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a problem and hope you can help me to link in a tab from the outside. It will every time just get the first link
This is my code:

The Navigationbar

> ```
>               <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Produktionsprozess</a> 
>                 <ul>
>                             <li><a href="#warenlogistik">Warenlogistik</a></li>
>                             <li><a href="#fotoproduktion">Fotoproduktion</a></li>
>                             <li><a href="#abstimmung">Abstimmung & Freigabe</a></li>
>                             <li><a href="#postproduction">Postproduktion</a></li>
> ```

The active Part:

```
            <ul data-animate class="row list-unstyled action-list inline-type-2 bottom-space" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 bottom-space has-corner-line corner-anim active">
                    <a class="tab secondary-headline has-icon corner-anim" href="#warenlogistik" aria-controls="warenlogistik" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fi flaticon-shuffle"></i>
                        <h3 class="maintitle">Waren<strong>logistik</strong></h3>
                        <p class="subtitle">Roadtrip to reach your goals</p>

                        <span class="corner corner-1"></span>
                        <span class="corner corner-2"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

The part i cant "reach":

```
                <li role="presentation" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 bottom-space has-corner-line corner-anim">
                    <a class="tab secondary-headline has-icon" href="#fotoproduktion" aria-controls="fotoproduktion" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fi flaticon-technology"></i>
                        <h3 class="maintitle">Foto<strong>produktion</strong></h3>
                        <p class="subtitle">Photography at its best</p>

                        <span class="corner corner-1"></span>
                        <span class="corner corner-2"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Also in the grid-container or accordion I have this code. It works for "warenlogistik" the first one, but not the second "fotoproduktion":

```
            <article class="row tab-pane in fade active" id="warenlogistik">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="images/pictures/produktionsprozess/warenlogistik.jpg" alt="Make a concept" />
                    </figure>
                </div>                      

<div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="secondary-headline">
                                <h3 class="maintitle">Waren<strong>logistik</strong></h3>
                                <h4 class="subtitle">Feel the innovation</h4>
                            </div> <p> text text text </p></div></article>


<article class="row tab-pane fade" id="fotoproduktion">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="images/pictures/produktionsprozess/fotoproduktion.jpg" alt="Make a concept" />
                            </figure>
                        </div><div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="secondary-headline">
                                <h3 class="maintitle">Foto<strong>Produktion</strong></h3>
                                <h4 class="subtitle">text text</h4>
                            </div><p> text text text </p>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

script.js:

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]') .on('shown.bs.tab', function() { 
        $window.trigger ('resize');
    });
```

script.min.js:
.....

```
a('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on ("shown.bs.tab",function()
{b.trigger("resize")}) ,
b.on("load",function()
{a(".preloader").
fadeOut("slow"), 
a("body").addClass("loaded")}
```

and than I have something in the bootstrap.min.js

I´ll try it since 4 hours... sorry i didnt got the Code - Panel.

Hopefully someone can help!

Regards
Markus

I tryed already in the script.js but it doesnt work:

```
$('#tab1 a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
})
```

});

edit:
Okay i got with the data-toggle="tab" the opening, but im still not able to jump to the part. its just opening

```
<li class="has-children"><a href="#">Produktionsprozess</a> 
                    <ul>
                                <li><a href="#warenlogistik" data-toggle="tab">Warenlogistik</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#fotoproduktion" data-toggle="tab">Fotoproduktion</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#abstimmung" data-toggle="tab">Abstimmung & Freigabe</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#postproduction" data-toggle="tab">Postproduktion</a></li>
```

also I added:

```
$(function () {
$('#fotoproduktion a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
})
```

To get an idea what Im talking about please take a look at this:
https://www.bnecreative.com/blog/deeplink-bootstrap-tabs/

The tap opening will work, thats not the problem anymore. But I want to open the nonactive tab and scroll down to it. Until now I have to open the tab with the link in the nav-bar and scroll down to the content manualy.

Comment: you want to use the navigation bar to toggle tabs?

Comment: yes i do - that would be great

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your question is that you want to be able to access individual tabs from `<a>` links. If so..

You are going to have to use jquery to direct the link instead of using a static link with an `href`.

**JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
    $('#tab1 a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="tab1" href="#postproduction">tab 1</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it doesnt solve the problem :( I edited the code for maybe some extra details (the active and inactive part)